# Function reference and pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm trying to make a cumulative density functions (CDF) for normal distribution by using a well-coded library. The inplementation of that library is irrelevant to my questions. So i only added interface here.

```
void cumnor ( double *arg, double *result, double *ccum );
```

Now, my member function interface:

```
double N(const double& x) const;
```

with implementation:

```
double EuropeanOption::N(const double& x) const
{ // cumulative density functions (CDF)
    
    double cum, ccum;
    cumnor(&x, &cum, &ccum);

    return cum; 
}
```

so my function basically take upper limit of the integration (x) in CDF and return value P.

but compiler throw me the following:

```
EuropeanOption.cpp: In member function ‘double EuropeanOption::N(const double&) const’:
EuropeanOption.cpp:82:9: error: invalid conversion from ‘const double*’ to ‘double*’ [-fpermissive]
  cumnor(&x, &cum, &ccum);
         ^~
In file included from EuropeanOption.hpp:3:0,
                 from EuropeanOption.cpp:3:
cdflib.hpp:60:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void cumnor(double*, double*, double*)’
 void cumnor ( double *arg, double *result, double *ccum );
      ^~~~~~
```

My question is how should I code this function? I only want to call it like **N(d1)**. I don't quite understand why i can't pass **&x** as first argument here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass `&x` to `cumnor()` because `x` is a reference to a `const double` but `cumnor()` expects a pointer to a non-const `double` instead.  Being non-const gives `cumnor()` *permission* to change the value of the `double` it is given, if it wants to.  If that is not actually the case, then it *should* take a pointer to a `const double` instead:

```cpp
void cumnor ( const double *arg, double *result, double *ccum );
```

On the other hand, there is really no good reason to pass a `double` by **const reference** at all.  Ideally, it should be passed **by value** instead, eg:

```cpp
void cumnor ( double arg, double *result, double *ccum );
...
double EuropeanOption::N(double x) const
{ // cumulative density functions (CDF)
    
    double cum, ccum;
    cumnor(x, &cum, &ccum);

    return cum; 
}
```

However, if making that change to `cumnor()` is not an option (ie, because you don't have access to change the library's interface), then you need to change `N()` instead to pass what `cumnor()` wants. For instance, by using a local `double` variable that is a *copy* of the `double` that `x` points to, eg:

```cpp
double EuropeanOption::N(const double& x) const
{ // cumulative density functions (CDF)
    
    double x_copied = x, cum, ccum;
    cumnor(&x_copied, &cum, &ccum);

    return cum; 
}
```

Or, if you know *for sure* that `cumnor()` will not change the value of the `double`, you can use `const_cast` instead (though, I'm sure people will discourage you from using this), eg:

```cpp
double EuropeanOption::N(const double& x) const
{ // cumulative density functions (CDF)
    
    double cum, ccum;
    cumnor(const_cast<double*>(&x), &cum, &ccum);

    return cum; 
}
```

Or, if you simply take `x` by value instead of by pointer, then passing `&x` to `cumnor()` would work fine, while maintaining the semantic that `N()` cannot alter the caller's `double` variable, eg:

```cpp
double EuropeanOption::N(double x) const
{ // cumulative density functions (CDF)
    
    double cum, ccum;
    cumnor(&x, &cum, &ccum);

    return cum; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Changing the library is not an option and making a copy seems not my style. I choose pass x by value. Very good explanation. pointers and references are hard concepts for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I don't quite understand why i can't pass &x as first argument here.

Passing `&x` to a function that expects `double*` as argument type is not right. If allowed, it would let the called funtion change the value of `x`, which is a `const`.

To resolve the problem, create a function local variable and use it.

```
double EuropeanOption::N(const double& x) const
{ // cumulative density functions (CDF)
    
    double temp_x = x;
    double cum, ccum;
    cumnor(&temp_x, &cum, &ccum);

    return cum; 
}
```

As an additional improvement, initialize `cum` and `ccum` to zero before using them in the call to `cumnor`.

```
double EuropeanOption::N(const double& x) const
{ // cumulative density functions (CDF)
    
    double temp_x = x;
    double cum = 0, ccum = 0;
    cumnor(&temp_x, &cum, &ccum);

    return cum; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this variable copy works well. Is there a particular reason to initialize cum and ccum before using them? From programming practice aspect speaking. Thank you

Comment: @YehuiHe "*Is there a particular reason to initialize cum and ccum before using them?*" - in case `cumnor()` doesn't set them, ie on failure. But if it always does set them, then initializing them beforehand is redundant.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I saw the code for cumnor(). It does always set them. I read always initialize variables ahead of function call just in case cause unpredictable value of uninitialized variables.